# Programatically made form doesn't return response on trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I made a new form programmatically for verification purpose after another form (pre-made) is submitted. Here is the code (**This script is bound to the pre-made form. And this `createVerificationForm()` is called inside a function triggered by the form `onSubmit`**):

```
/**
 * Create a Google Form to verify the submitted request
 * @param {Array<String>} The submitted data
 * @return {Form} The created verification form
 */
function createVerificationForm(submissionData) {
  // Create Form
  var form = FormApp.create("Request Verification");

  // Add Data to be verified as description
  form.setDescription("Show the details here");

  // Add options to verify or deny
  form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      .setTitle("Verify the request")
      .setChoiceValues([REQUEST_VERIFIED, REQUEST_DENIED])
      .setRequired(true);

  // Set the form trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('setRequestStatus')
           .forForm(form)
           .onFormSubmit()
           .create();

  return form;
}
```

I also create a trigger for the verification form. The `setRequestStatus` will get the response and use it accordingly. Because I'm unable to get the response, I tried to `stringify()` the event object to check if the response is actually received by `setRequestStatus()`. Here is what it looks like

```
/**
 * Set Request Status.
 * Triggered by Verification Form
 * @param e {Object} Event Object sent by the trigger
 */
function setRequestStatus(e) {
  var response = e.response;
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();

// I use email because somehow Logger doesn't work
  MailApp.sendEmail(REVIEWER_EMAIL, "Verification Result", JSON.stringify(e));


}
```

And here is the result:

```
{"response":{},"source":{},"authMode":{},"triggerUid":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Everything but `triggerUid` is absent. Does it have anything to do with creating form and setting the trigger programmatically?

FYI, looking at the response tab (when you open the form through GDrive), the response is actually recorded.

**EDIT:**

Per tehhowch suggestion, I tweaked `setRequestStatus()` into this:

```
function setRequestStatus(e) {
  var response = e.response;
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();

  console.log("FormResponse: " + itemResponses[0].getResponse());
}
```

The result of the log is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method "getResponse" of undefined. at setRequestStatus(FormResponder:139)
```

It seems that there is no `ItemResponse` returned by `getItemResponses()`. It's weird considering that checking the response gathered by opening the form directly on Google Drive does show that the response is indeed there.

**EDIT2:**

I tried to `log` the event object content in case it helps. Here are the code and the log screencap.

```
/**
 * Set Request Status.
 * Triggered by Verification Form
 * @param e {Object} Event Object sent by the trigger
 */
function setRequestStatus(e) {
  var response = e.response;
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();

  console.log(e);
  console.log(e.response);
  console.log(e.response.getItemResponses());
  console.log(e.response.getItemResponses()[0]);
}
```

[image: Log Screencap]

Notice that the FormResponse object is there but when I tried to access it, it comes out empty. I'm starting to think that this can be an issue Google should look into.

**EDIT3**

After looking at [stepvda's similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51082374/6220384), I assumed that this problem maybe has something to do with my script is bound to a form (and that it already has an `onSubmit` trigger) or with another functionality (such as sending email and editing spreadsheet). So I tested my script on a new unbound project by simplifying it. Here is the code (I made a couple variation on how the trigger is attached):

```
function testTrigger() {
//  Attach to a premade form (WORKED!)
//  var form = FormApp.openById('1lRKrqxuQm50EY4zMsf8b_myrN9KIaooFS7Elv48XD3U');
//  
//  ScriptApp.newTrigger('logDataFromForm')
//           .forForm(form)
//           .onFormSubmit()
//           .create();

// Attach to a programmatically made form (WORKED!)
//  var form = FormApp.create("Auto Trigger Test");
//  form.addTextItem()
//      .setTitle('How are you?');
//  
//  ScriptApp.newTrigger('logDataFromForm')
//           .forForm(form)
//           .onFormSubmit()
//           .create();

// Attach to a programmatically made form from a function (WORKED!)
  var submissionData = ['Blacky', 'blacky@dog.com'];
  createVerificationForm(submissionData);
}

function logDataFromForm(e) {
  console.log("I'm auto triggered");

  console.log(e);
  console.log(e.response);
  console.log(e.response.getItemResponses());
  console.log(e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse());
}

function createVerificationForm(submissionData) {
  // Create Form
  var form = FormApp.create("Are you dumb? (test)");

  // Add Data to be verified as description
  form.setDescription(
    "Some random description" +
    "\nName\t\t\t\t: " + submissionData[0] +
    "\nEmail\t\t\t\t: " + submissionData[1] +
    "\n"
  );

  // Add options to verify or deny
  var choices = ['Yes', 'No'];
  form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      .setTitle("Are you dumb?")
      .setChoiceValues(choices)
      .setRequired(true);

  // Set the form trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('logDataFromForm')
           .forForm(form)
           .onFormSubmit()
           .create();
}
```

The result is:

[image: Result]

It works!!

Then I tried to test this on another project and just like the first time, it is bound to a pre-made form. `testTrigger()` is now triggered by the bound form's `onSubmit` trigger.
[image: trigger snapshot]
Here is how it looks like (other functions are the same):

```
function testTrigger(e) {  
// Attach to a programmatically made form from a function
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var submissionData = [itemResponses[0].getResponse(), itemResponses[1].getResponse()];
  createVerificationForm(submissionData);
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Result]

It doesn't work! I can't really confirm this but based on this test, MAYBE the response is not returned with the event object because it has something to do with the script bound to a form with already created trigger (in this case, `onSubmit`).

Comment: Use Stackdriver logging for complex objects or remote executions. `console.log(e)`, then `View -> Stackdriver`

Comment: If it's a bug, you can submit an issue in the Issue Tracker or search for an existing issue.  [Link to issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)  You can get the response ID from the event object and then get the response by ID.  I wouldn't try to get the response from the event object.

Comment: @SandyGood I've submitted this to the issue tracker. As for getting the response from the event object, isn't that how you get it?

Comment: There is often more than one way to get to the same end result.  `var rspnsID = e.response.getId(); var theRspns = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponse(rspnsID);`

Comment: Is this the link to the Issue Tracker?  [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110971988)

Comment: @SandyGood yes. I'm surprised you found that.

Comment: Click the star on the issue tracker to show that it is important.

Comment: @SandyGood I didn't know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed similar functionality which is working fine. You may want to compare with the code I wrote. Have a look at the createNewForm() and submitForm(e) function  [here](https://github.com/stepvda/ExtremePlanning/blob/master/form.gs).

You may also want to just look at the contents of the responses array. I noticed that JSON.stringify doesn't reveal everything here. In this scenario you can't use the debugger so you'll have to use the Logger.log() function to see what is really in the responses.

Comment: `console.log` >>> `Logger.log` since Stackdriver will persist the logs beyond the current script execution. I.e. actual logs, not BS in-editor-only-the-most-recent-execution snippets

Comment: good point, though in this case, you typically know when the onSubmit event was triggered. at least in my case I was testing by submitting a form and then directly hitting cmd+enter

Comment: I can't see anything different with mine compared to yours. I'm not sure if I miss something.

Comment: I did access the contents of the responses array. And it returns empty.

Comment: strange. maybe you can try with a TextItem in your form to go back to something simple. Although this shouldn't be the case here, I noticed that with pre-filled forms you need to create response arrays with MultipleChoiceItems. So give it  at try with `form.addTextItem().setTitle('test item')`

Comment: I also did a quick JSON.stringify test this morning and I'm getting the same result like in your code `[18-06-29 08:54:54:147 CEST] {"response":{},"source":{},"authMode":{},"triggerUid":"21899999999999"}` So this comes back to my point that stringify doesn't work here. As you've seen in my code I am actually able to get values out of `var responses = e.response.getItemResponses();     
  var feedback = responses[0].getResponse();`  I'll have another think about this one. Will let you know if I have any new inspiration of what could be wrong.

Comment: @stepvda Regarding `JSON.stringify()`, it indeed doesn't convert the object properly into string. That's why I use `console.log()` instead. As for your suggestion, I already tried that before and after trying it again, the `FormResponse` still has no `ItemResponse`. `getItemResponse()` will return empty array. I have no idea why yours works and mine not.